# How can I ensure a transfer is done in binary mode using the cadaver command-line tool for WebDAV upload?

Tags: webdav, solaris-10, cadaver

I'm doing a transfer of a tar.gz file to a client WebDAV server. I want to ensure that the transfer is done in binary mode, i.e. like the "bin" option in ftp.

The man command doesn't indicate anything about the default transfer mode.

Can anyone confirm, or otherwise, that cadaver uses binary mode by default ?? I am on a Solaris 10 server.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

WebDAV is HTTP. And in HTTP, the payload is always transferred "binary".